# issue with VueJS loading a component in specific route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuejs3, vue-router4

I've want to get this behaviour :
When I click on a blogItem, then it loads the blogtoread component in this route url/blog/{i}.
I've got this code :

main.js :

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import BlogToRead from '../src/components/BlogToRead.vue'
import HelloTest from '../src/components/HelloWorld.vue'


const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: App },
  { path: '/blog/:id/:title', component: BlogToRead, name: 'blog-post'},
  { path:'/test', component: HelloTest}
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(), // Use history mode for cleaner URLs
  routes,
})

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(router) // Add the router instance to the app
app.mount('#app') // Mount the app on the element with id 'app'
```

BlogItem.vue :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="blog-item" @click="handleCardClick()">
    <h3 class="blog-title">{{ title }}</h3>
    <p class="blog-preview">{{ preview }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
  
  <script>
  export default {
    props: {
      title: String,
      preview: String,
      postId: Number, // Assuming you have a unique ID for each blog post
      content: String,
      date: Date,
      author: String,
    },
    methods: {
        handleCardClick() {
          console.log("yey");
          console.log(this.$route);
          const postId = this.postId;
          const postTitle = this.title;
          console.log("test 1 :   " + this.$route.params.id + "  et " + postId +" et "+ postTitle );
          this.$router.push({ name: 'blog-post', params: { id: postId, title: postTitle } });
        },
      },
  };
  </script>
```

App.vue :

```
<template>
  <div class="app-container">
    <Navbar /> <!-- Include the Navbar component directly -->
    <Banner />
    <div class="main-container">
    <div class="portefolio-container"> <!-- Container for PortefolioCard components -->
      <PortefolioCard
        title="Project Title 1"
        :imageURL="require('../src/assets/PP.jpg')"
        description="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit..."
        category="Project Category 1"
        @card-clicked="handleCardClick"
      />
      <PortefolioCard
        title="Project Title 2"
        :imageURL="require('../src/assets/PP.jpg')"
        description="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit..."
        category="Project Category 2"
        @card-clicked="handleCardClick"
      />
      <PortefolioCard
        title="Project Title 3"
        :imageURL="require('../src/assets/PP.jpg')"
        description="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit..."
        category="Project Category 3"
        @card-clicked="handleCardClick"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="blog-container">
        <div class="blog-column">
          <BlogItem
            v-for="post in blogPosts"
            :key="post.id"
            :title="post.title"
            :preview="post.preview"
            :postId="post.id"
            :content="post.content"
            :date="post.date"
            :author="post.author"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
//import HelloWorld from "@/components/HelloWorld.vue";
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar.vue";
import PortefolioCard from "@/components/PortefolioCard.vue";
import BlogItem from "./components/BlogItem.vue";
import Banner from "@/components/Banner.vue";
import axios from "axios";


export default {
  components: {
    //HelloWorld,
    Navbar,
    PortefolioCard,
    BlogItem,
    Banner,
  },
  methods: {
    handleCardClick(title) {
      // Handle the card click event here
      console.log(`Clicked on card with title: ${title}`);
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      blogPosts: [],
    };
  },
  created() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5287/api/blogposts")
      .then((response) => {
        this.blogPosts = response.data;
        console.log(this.blogPosts)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Axios request error:", error);
      });
  },
};
```

As you can see in the blogItem I've added a couple of console.log, it always return correctly the postId and Title props, meaning it finds it correctly.

When I'm clicking on a blogpost in my vue app in the browser I get this error **content.js:33 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Illegal argument undefined**

Also I get this error when I'm just running the app with no click event triggered, it makes me guess that there has to be something not right with how I've configured things in the first place.

Can you help me ?

I'm expecting to load the blogtoread component alone not the App.vue component which contains the other components

Here's the fullstack of the error :

BlogItem.vue:23 {fullPath: '/', path: '/', query: {…}, hash: '', name: undefined, …}
BlogItem.vue:26 test 1 :   undefined  et 1 et First Article

```
content.js:33 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Illegal argument undefined
    at e.exports (content.js:33:95534)
    at content.js:73:1593807
    at p (content.js:73:185751)
    at Generator._invoke (content.js:73:185504)
    at Generator.next (content.js:73:186114)
    at n (content.js:73:192157)
    at s (content.js:73:192360)
```

the content.js is a file from Vue it appears.

Comment: What's content.js? Please, post the whole error including callstack. If it's not a file in your project then you can check on your side by clicking it. "I'm expecting to load the blogtoread component alone not the App.vue component " - why? App is root component, it's rendered any way

Comment: I've added the stack at the end of my post.
Maybe my issue lies in the fact that App is rendered anyway ?

Comment: This isn't an issue because root com is supposed to be rendered any way, a vue app cannot work otherwise, so probably there's a misunderstanding how a router works. There's no <router-view> in App for starters, you can't expect route view to be rendered correctly. The app doesn't have source maps configured correctly, so call stack isn't useful for debugging, it contains low-level details, I'd guess it's the router error because of the mentioned problem with route view

Comment: ok so in the main.js I need to add routerview right ?

Comment: You need to add specifically <router-view> to App.vue

Comment: when I add the router view to the app.vue template, where is supposed to be placed, I can't seem to grasp it's role. without it my app.vue still get rendered anyway

Comment: It's supposed to be in the place where you intend to show route component. Router view is a part of root component (App), not a replacement. If you don't want to show some parts of App in some routes this means they need to be extracted to other route views.  `{ path: '/', component: App }` - this should have been Home instead of App or so, otherwise this would be recursion. "without it my app.vue still get rendered anyway" - because it's root comp here `createApp(App)`

Comment: Check how regular routed apps are structured https://github.com/vuejs/router/tree/main/packages/playground/src

Comment: it looks like this part is what 'im missing : 

<RouterView :name="viewName" v-slot="{ Component, route }">
      <Transition
        :name="route.meta.transition || 'fade'"
        mode="out-in"
        @before-enter="flushWaiter"
        @before-leave="setupWaiter"
      >

but In the exemple it's trigger based off of a button, in my case i'd like it to respond off of an onclick event

Comment: In the most simple representation it's just literally <RouterView>. It's a placeholder for route view component